# Adding a proxy settings to Microsoft Graph Client in Java

Tags: java, proxy, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to implement GraphClient, below is a sample code which is working fine...

```
   ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = 
              new ClientCredentialProvider(clientId,
                      scopes,
                      clientSecret,
                      b2cTenant,
                      endpoint);
    
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();
```

This is working fine...but in some case from where the code is being run, there is a proxy, so I need to setup proxy to connect to internet. I need to setup proxy and pass it to graphClient somehow to tell make a call via proxy.

I was trying to find a document but could not get any through I got this...

```
ProxyOptions proxyOptions = new ProxyOptions(ProxyOptions.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl, proxyPort));
proxyOptions.setCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword);

final UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .username(username)
                    .password(password)
                    .httpClient(HttpClient.createDefault(new HttpClientOptions().setProxyOptions(proxyOptions)))
                    .build();
```

But the problem is the "ProxyOptions" isnt in Maven and I am not sure what library it is part of.

Can anyone suggest an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the answer...

```
        ProxyOptions proxyOptions = new ProxyOptions(
               ProxyOptions.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, hostPort));
        
        HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions();
        clientOptions.setProxyOptions(proxyOptions); 
        
        HttpClient azHttpClient = HttpClient.createDefault(clientOptions);
        
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .httpClient(azHttpClient)
                .build();

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
            new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);
        
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, hostPort));
        
        OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .newBuilder()
                .proxy(proxy)
                .build();

        graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .buildClient();
```

Comment: in terms of Maven, <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please - where is the DefaultClientConfig defined? cannot find it in any dependency :(

Comment: @Frk I am updating the answer, MS has updated the library.

Comment: @Frk Proxy class belongs to java.net.Proxy and OkHttpClient belongs to okhttp3 library, everything else is from com.azure.

Comment: Please upvote if this solves your issue, thank you!

Comment: code works - proxying doesn't :( maybe some issue on our network side

Comment: @Frk double check the host address and port?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use system properties then try to configure via

https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort

Comment: Never change system properties like this. NOT recommended.